# How to delete a repository and add a new one in Android studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control, bitbucket

I was working with VCS enabled in Android Studio and pushed my code to a repository that I had created in BitBucket. However, now the team I'm working with has created a new repository also on BitBucket and I have to switch my entire project there. So how do I stop VCS in my current project, and push code to a new repoositroy with a new link from scratch?

Also, in the first repository that I was working with only the "java" folder was pushed and not the rest. Now in the new repository I want to be able to commit and push changes made in all other files as well like "res" etc.

Comment: to remove a git repository just delete the .git folder. But make a backup in case you need some data from the branches.

Comment: Where can I find the .git folder? I did a search and couldn't find any such folder.

Comment: It's hidden. You need to switch showing hidden files on.

Answer (score 9):

U can remove connection from git repository.

step 1 :Open git bash.

step 2 : navigate to the master folder. '

step 3 : $ git remote rm origin

The git remote will now be removed from the repository.

Now u can add new connection by using VCS->Git->+add.

Answer (score 0):

[[Remove and add git]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57074361/4770877)

or you can add/edit remote url

```
VCS -> Git -> Remotes...
```