# Remove old and add new git in android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control

I have tried to configure android studio with git and messed up.

How to completely remove old git that I could create new one?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to change remote or update the version of your git? Or might you want to drop all the git settings for you project and add new ones?

Comment: Drop all git settings. I want to create/configure a new git using some tutorial, but can't because of my previous git.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In order to drop the current git repository and create a new one you need to:

- Go to the project's directory: `cd PROJECT_DIRECTORY`
- Remove all the git specific files: `rm -rf $(find . -name ".git*")`
- Initialize a new git repository: `git init`

This doesn't remove your project's files, only git configs

Comment: @user2983041, you can install [git bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and execute all the steps there as if it is a `unix` bash shell. If you integrate the git bash into explorer then you can right click on the project directory and select **Git Bash Here** then you can skip the first step

Answer (score 9):

You can remove GIT from your Android Studio Project in File → Settings → Version Control → In VCS select  and Apply.

[image]

Then you can add it back in VSC Menu → Enable Version Control Integration → Select GIT → OK button.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just a simple way

Open the terminal in android studio.

```
git remote set-url origin <NEW GIT URL>
```

now the project url is changed from old link to new one.
Then you can use >

```
git init
```

and upload your files.
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

Delete the .git folder & .gitignore and start again.

Google for how to display hidden folders on windows to see the .git folder.

Comment: Now I can't see any data except local.properties and external libraries in my Android studio project view

Comment: git is a nightmare for stuff like this, do you still have your java source files

Comment: Java source files are in place, but still unable to run project on studio

Comment: Go to File->Project Structure-> Project Settings -> Modules.

Click on the green colored + and add new module. select Application module and set the content root to your project module.

Click next and then finish.

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio terminal in your project dir:
Windows:

```
rd /s /q ".git"
```

Linux/Mac:

```
rm -rf .git
```

Answer (score 2):

I find the top answer little bit too complicated, although fully functional. So here is maybe little bit easier to understand practice:

Assuming you already have project, and you want to change target (Bitbucket in my case) directory.

- Go to project directory: `cd Your/project/location`
- Find your current remote: `git remote` (its name will be probably `origin`)
- Delete it: `git remote remove yourOldRemoteName`
- Make sure you deleted the remote: `git remote` (should display nothing)
- Create new remote: `git remote add yourNewRemoteName repositoryUrl`

(If you are using Bitbucket, your url will be something like `https://yourUsername@bitbucket.org/your-company/yourRepository.git` and you will find it by clicking `Clone` button in source folder of your repository or when creating the repository.)

Hope this will be useful!

Comment: Take a look at the comments below the question, I explicitly asked the OP if they want to change the remote and the OP stated that they just want all the git files to be gone.

Answer (score 2):

If you delete a git repository from github, you should also delete a folder name .git from your Android Studio root directory.

Then you have to close the project. And re-open it in Android Studio.

Then do these things:
1)  VCS -> Enable Version Control Integration -> Git
2)  In Project view in Android Studio, select the project root folder and right click on it. Then go to Git -> Add, after that Git -> Commit Directory, and then Git -> Repository -> Push .

Whenever you get prompts in this way, just click on appropriate options.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the git folder in Project directory
2. Run this command `git init` in Terminal
3. Vcs=> Git=>remote and add new
4. Paste the new git URL
5. After, verify your GitHub credentials

Now new git attached to your project

Answer (score 0):

Remove  and add git

```
//progect_path is path where .git is located
cd <progect_path> 
rm -fr .git
git init
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the better solucion using Android Studio with Flutter projects was:

- Create a new project in Android Studio
- Close Android Studio
- Outside from Android Studio, with Finder (Mac) copy from my old (corrupted) project the entire lib folder and the pubspec.yaml file to the new one, overwriting.
- Enable Git in the new project from Android Studio again