# Remove git file

Tags: git

I am trying to run the command `git rm -f .git`. It is saying

> '.git' did not match any files.

I can't recall if it is the exact command, but clearly something is off and I have been unable to find online what I'm looking for. The issue I am trying to resolve is delete the `.git` file. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Do you really want to remove the `.git` folder? That deletes the repository with all the history. If you have no backup repo, it will be lost forever.

Comment: Take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990372/remove-old-and-add-new-git-in-android-studio/31991358#31991358)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to actually delete the `.git` folder, just run

`rm -rf .git`

I don't think `git rm` will allow you to delete the `.git` folder, as that is what defines the repository itself.

Comment: Thanks. I think that worked - pretty obvious in hindsight, but I'm a tad rusty. I'll accept in a few minutes when I'm allowed

Comment: `git rm` won't work because it tells git to remove files from it's working directory, which `.git` is not a part of.